# random forest tuning - tree depth and number of trees

Tags: random-forest

I have basic question about tuning a random forest classifier. Is there any relation between the number of trees and the tree depth? Is it necessary that the tree depth should be smaller than the number of trees?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Random forests is a machine learning method.  His question totally belongs here.

Comment: I have never heard of a rule of thumb ratio between the number of trees and tree depth.  Generally you want as many trees as will improve your model.  The depth of the tree should be enough to split each node to your desired number of observations.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  here's my thumb rule :)

Comment: There has been some work that says best depth is 5-8 splits.  It is, of course, problem and data dependent.  Think about the response as a surface with a multivariate input, and each leaf as wanting to split on regions with highest magnitude of slope.  If you have enough points to inform the math, then more splits will be made to represent the surface until you hit a "max depth" wall. If your data is sparse enough or noisy enough, then it can't cleanly detect slope, and isn't going to split as well.  If there is a relationship, it also relates to mtry - the number of columns informing split.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with Tim that there is no thumb ratio between the number of trees and tree depth. Generally you want as many trees as will improve your model. More trees also mean more computational cost and after a certain number of trees, the improvement is negligible. As you can see in figure below, after sometime there is no significant improvement in error rate even if we are increasing no of tree.

[image]

The depth of the tree meaning length of tree you desire.  Larger tree helps you to convey more info whereas smaller tree gives less precise info.So depth should large enough to split each node to your desired number of observations.

Below is example of short tree(leaf node=3) and long tree(leaf node=6)  for Iris dataset: Short tree(leaf node=3) gives less precise info compared to long tree(leaf node=6).

Short tree(leaf node=3):

[image]

Long tree(leaf node=6):

[image]

Answer (score 27):

For most practical concerns, I agree with Tim.

Yet, other parameters do affect when the ensemble error converges as a function of added trees. I guess limiting the tree depth typically would make the ensemble converge a little earlier. I would rarely fiddle with tree depth, as though computing time is lowered, it does not give any other bonus. Lowering bootstrap sample size both gives lower run time and lower tree correlation, thus often a better model performance at comparable run-time.
A not so mentioned trick: When RF model explained variance is lower than 40%(seemingly noisy data), one can lower samplesize to ~10-50% and increase trees to e.g. 5000(usually unnecessary many). The ensemble error will converge later as a function of trees. But, due to lower tree correlation, the model becomes more robust and will reach a lower OOB error level converge plateau.

You see below samplesize gives the best long run convergence, whereas maxnodes starts from a lower point but converges less. For this noisy data, limiting maxnodes still better than default RF. For low noise data, the decrease in variance by lowering maxnodes or sample size does not make the increase in bias due to lack-of-fit.

For many practical situations, you would simply give up, if you only could explain 10% of variance. Thus is default RF typically fine. If your a quant, who can bet on hundreds or thousands of positions, 5-10% explained variance is awesome.

**the green curve is maxnodes which kinda tree depth but not exactly.**

[image]

```
library(randomForest)

X = data.frame(replicate(6,(runif(1000)-.5)*3))
ySignal = with(X, X1^2 + sin(X2) + X3 + X4)
yNoise = rnorm(1000,sd=sd(ySignal)*2)
y = ySignal + yNoise
plot(y,ySignal,main=paste("cor="),cor(ySignal,y))

#std RF
rf1 = randomForest(X,y,ntree=5000) 
print(rf1)
plot(rf1,log="x",main="black default, red samplesize, green tree depth")

#reduced sample size
rf2 = randomForest(X,y,sampsize=.1*length(y),ntree=5000) 
print(rf2)
points(1:5000,rf2$mse,col="red",type="l")

#limiting tree depth (not exact )
rf3 = randomForest(X,y,maxnodes=24,ntree=5000)
print(rf2)
points(1:5000,rf3$mse,col="darkgreen",type="l")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I could understand to some extent what you mean, however, since I am still getting used to this whole concept of developing random forest models, I have a few more questions based on your answer. What exactly is the tree correlation and how do you measure it? Is the OOB estimate and ensemble error the same things? Since these could be very basic, you could let me know if there is an article if I can read up to understand the terms better.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tree correlation means that 2 trees are correlated in terms of predictor variable on which split is made. In bagging, OOB(out of bag) means that on average,we are able to use only 2/3rd of our dataset for building our tree and rest 1/3rd are not used. So we are trying to make prediction from OOB 1/3rd dataset.

Comment: thanks, this looks great, nice tip! But for me it didn't work, setting sampsize to .1, .2, .3, etc. didn't result in lower mse or higher rsq, not even for 5000 trees. It was only negligibly lower for .5  (3.371 instead of the default 3.377 :-)).

Answer (score 19):

It is true that generally more trees will result in better accuracy. However, more trees also mean more computational cost and after a certain number of trees, the improvement is negligible. An article from Oshiro et al. (2012) pointed out that, based on their test with 29 data sets,  after 128 of trees there is no significant improvement(which is inline with the graph from Soren).

Regarding the tree depth, standard random forest algorithm grow the full decision tree without pruning. A single decision tree do need pruning in order to overcome over-fitting issue. However, in random forest, this issue is eliminated by random selecting the variables and the OOB action.

Reference:
Oshiro, T.M., Perez, P.S. and Baranauskas, J.A., 2012, July. How many trees in a random forest?. In MLDM (pp. 154-168).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your data set.

I have an example where I was building the Random Forest classifier on Adult Income dataset and reducing the depth of trees (from 42 to 6) improved the performance of the model. The side effect of reducing the depth of trees was [How can I reduce the long feature vector which is a list of double values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364539/how-can-i-reduce-the-long-feature-vector-which-is-a-list-of-double-valuessmaller) model size (in RAM and disk space after save)

Regarding the number of trees, I was doing the [experiment](https://mljar.com/blog/how-many-trees-in-random-forest/) on 72 classification tasks from OpenML-CC18 benchmark and I found that:

- the more rows in the data, the more trees are needed,
- the best performance is obtained by tuning the number of trees with 1 tree precision. Train large Random Forest (for example with 1000 trees) and then use validation data to find optimal number of trees.